# .NET MAUI query parameter and community toolkit issue

Tags: c#, observable, maui, master-detail, maui-community-toolkit

I tried to pass an object parameter thru `ViewModel Books` to `ViewModel Book Detail`. I defined both viewmodels as `ObservableObject` and used a dictionary in **ViewModel Books** to pass parateter like below:

I expect to have `Title = this.Book.Name;` to work and get the value, but the `this. Book` or even `Book` property alone is null, but I can get its value in Details XAML page. I need it on the DetailsViewModel constructor. What's my issue?

**BooksViewModel.cs**

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task GoToDestinationAsync(Book book)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(DetailsPage)}", true,
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"Book",book}
    });
}
```

**DetailsViewModel.cs**

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Book), "Book")]
public partial class BookDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Book book;

    public BookDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Title = this.Book.Name;
    }
}
```

**DetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailsPage(MonkeyDetailsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    }
}
```

**AppShell.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DetailsPage), typeof(DetailsPage));
    }
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<BooksViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<BookDetailsViewModel>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<DetailsPage>();


        return builder. Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t assume properties have been set when the constructor runs

Comment: @Jason Oh really? so where should I populate my required data to view? (I'm new in .NET MAUI). I am a web developer, in ASP.NET we populate some part of calculations and service use in the constructor as you know, what shall I do in here?

Comment: in C# you should never assume that anything runs before the constructor.  How you approach this depends on what you need to do with the data.  What do you need `Title` for in the constructor?

Comment: Of course not, the Title was just an example of accessing the object. I require the id to populate other required data fetching and calculations

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, constructor runs first so you cannot get the Book property. I assume that you may want to set the initial value for Title property. But I think you don't have to set the value in constructor. You could just set the value in Setter method:

```
    Book book;
    public Book Book
    {
        ...
        set
        {
            book = value;
            Title = book.Name;
        }                      
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    string title;
```

Also, in MAUI page has OnAppearing method, you could also set the value in OnAppearing method in code behind.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    //get the value from viewmodel and set the value

}
```

For more info, you may refer to [Pass data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data)

Hope it helps!